# Free Native Launcher For Java At Linux and Mac

Tags: java

My Java application require a huge memory heap. I need to launch my application using

java -Xms32m -Xmx128m xyz.jar

Hence, I would like to create native launcher for my Java application, where I can pass the JVM heap size parameters in. I plan to use JSmooth http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/ for Windows platform.

However, I would also like to create native launcher for Linux and Mac. May I know which open source/ free software can help me to do so?

LaunchAnywhere
http://www.zerog.com/iamanual/usermanual_ia55/WebHelp/launchanywhere/abo12e.htm

seem good. But it is a commercial software.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the answer you want, but I would use an [application bundle on MacOS](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/00-Intro/JavaDevelopment.html) and a simple shell script on linux/unix.

Only reason really is that the end user experience of using web start and or shell scripts on OSX just isn't that great, Mac users expect everything to work like a Mac app bundle.

Comment: Shell script + .desktop file with nice icon is indeed quite enough for Linux.

Comment: After having some informal survey on different platform users, here is my conclusion :

Most Windows users, of course, exe is the best.

Most Linux users are comfortable in starting their application through command line, by invoking a script.

Most MAC users prefer to have native Mac app bundle.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, you might consider using [Java Webstart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Webstart). It's a bit more than just a launcher, but it can do the things you want. It eases deployment, and you can also install applications manually and use them offline, and it's cross-platform.

Or you can just write a simple launcher shell script. Many apps do that, and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use '/Developer/Applications/Utilities/Jar Bundler' to package your Jar as a Mac app. This makes it easy to specify an icon, launch params for heap size, minimum Java versions, System properties, etc.